# QML ListView indexAt() function always returns wrong value

Tags: android, c++, qt, listview, qml

We are developing QT cross platform application. We have one conversation ListView(Basically list of chats using qml ListView) and requirement is to perform some functionality depending on the first visible index in screen. to find first Visible index we are using function indexAt(real, real). Function call always returns -1.

Documentation which we refereed can be found here [QML ListView](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-listview.html#indexAt-method)

Here is sample code snippet

```
ListView
  {
    id: id_conversation_list
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: Conversations
    spacing: 5
    delegate: id_loader
    clip: true

    onContentYChanged:
    {
      console.log("====index=====  " + id_conversation_list.indexAt(0, contentY));
    }
}
```

Even i tested with fixed values like (0, 0) or (10, 50) but function always returns -1. If anybody already faced same issue please guide us. Is there any other possible way to find first visible index in qml Listview.

Comment: Impossible to answer without the delegate code.

Comment: thanks dtech, it was delegate issue. We have bit complex code for delegate. using Component Loader we areLoading Component depending on Model object type. there are more than 6 such sub Component. after adding width=parent.width to each component issue got fixed.